# How can I map path from API into the React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am planning to map the path that I got from the API. It will be set into the routeList. Then I want to map into one of the children for my `"/app"` route.

```js
const [routeList, setRouteList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all([
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/rights"),
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/children")
  ])
    .then((res) => {
      setRouteList([...res[0].data, ...res[1].data]);
    });
}, []);
```

```
const element = useRoutes([
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: LazyLoad("login/Login"),
  },
  {
    path: "/app",
    element: <AuthComponent> 
   {LazyLoad("sandbox/Sandbox")}</AuthComponent>,
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          element: <Redirect to="/app/home" />,
        },
        routeList.map((item) => {
          `path: ${item.key}, element: 
${LocalRouterMapping[item.key]}`;
        }),
        {
          path: "*",
          element: 
    LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission"),
          },
        ],
     },
    ]);
```

But I get an error for doing this

```js
routeList.map((item) => {
  `path: ${item.key}, element: ${LocalRouterMapping[item.key]}`;
}),
```

The error from the command prompt is  `Line 40:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`.

I tried to change the format but still not working.

I have another issue my element needed to be wrapped in LazyLoad function to use React.Suspence. May I know how can I do it?

```
const LazyLoad = (path) => {
const Comp = React.lazy(() => 
  import(`../views/${path}`));
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
      <Comp />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};
```

And here is how I do it but the path with the element is not created. I will just always redirect to the path: "*"

```
      routeList.map((item) => ({
      path: item.key,
      element: LazyLoad(`${LocalRouterMapping[item.key]}`),
    })),
```

Here's my LocalRouterMapping

```
const LocalRouterMapping = {
  "/home": "dashboard/Dashboard",
  "/user-manage/list": "user-manage/UserList",
  "/access-manage/access/list": "access-manage/AccessList",
  "/access-manage/role/list": "access-manage/RoleList",
  "/news-manage/add": "inventory/CreateInventory",
  "/news-manage/draft": "inventory/InventoryDraft",
  "/news-manage/category": "inventory/InventoryCategory",
  "/audit-manage/audit": "audit/AuditInventory",
  "/audit-manage/list": "audit/AuditList",
};
```

These are the data from axios [image: datafromAxios]

Here's my whole code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import Redirect from "../components/Redirect";
import axios from "axios";

const LocalRouterMapping = {
"/home": "dashboard/Dashboard",
"/user-manage/list": "user-manage/UserList",
"/access-manage/access/list": "access-manage/AccessList",
"/access-manage/role/list": "access-manage/RoleList",
"/news-manage/add": "inventory/CreateInventory",
"/news-manage/draft": "inventory/InventoryDraft",
"/news-manage/category": "inventory/InventoryCategory",
"/audit-manage/audit": "audit/AuditInventory",
"/audit-manage/list": "audit/AuditList",};
export default function IndexRouter() {
  const [routeList, setRouteList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {Promise.all([axios.get("http://localhost:5000/rights"), axios.get("http://localhost:5000/children")]).then((res) => {
  const combinedRoutes = [...res[0].data, ...res[1].data];
  setRouteList(combinedRoutes.filter((item) => LocalRouterMapping[item.key]));
});
}, []);
const element = useRoutes([
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: LazyLoad("login/Login"),
  },
  {
    path: "/app",
    element: <AuthComponent> {LazyLoad("sandbox/Sandbox")} </AuthComponent>,
   children: [
    {
      path: "",
      element: <Redirect to="/app/home" />,
    },
    routeList.map((item) => ({
      path: item.key.slice(1),
      element: <AuthComponent>{LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key])}</AuthComponent>,
    })),
    {
      path: "*",
      element: LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission"),
    },
  ],
},
{
  path: "/dashboard",
  element: <AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("dashboard/Dashboard")}</AuthComponent>,
},
{
  path: "/product",
  element: <AuthComponent> 
 {LazyLoad("dashboard/Dashboard")} 
 </AuthComponent>,
      },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Redirect to="/app" />,
    },
    {
      path: "*",
      element: LazyLoad("notFound/NotFound"),
    },
  ]);
  return element;
}

function AuthComponent({ children }) {
const isLogin = localStorage.getItem("token");
return isLogin ? children : <Redirect to="/login" />;
}

const LazyLoad = (path) => {
const Comp = React.lazy(() => import(`../views/${path}`));
return (
  <React.Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
    <Comp />
  </React.Suspense>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using Route component instead of using the useRoute.

Here's my source code using the same mapping style.

```
const LocalRouterMapping = {
  "/home": "dashboard/Dashboard",
  "/user-manage/list": "user-manage/UserList",
  "/access-manage/access/list": "access-manage/AccessList",
  "/access-manage/role/list": "access-manage/RoleList",
  "/inventory-manage/add": "inventory/CreateInventory",
  "/inventory-manage/list": "inventory/InventoryList",
  "/inventory-manage/preview/:id": "inventory/InventoryDetails",
  "/inventory-manage/update/:id": "inventory/InventoryUpdate",
  "/inventory-manage/category": "inventory/InventoryCategory",
};

<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={LazyLoad("login/Login")} />
  <Route path="/app" element={LazyLoad("sandbox/Sandbox")}>
    <Route path="" element={<Navigate to={"home"} />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission")}</AuthComponent>} />
    {routeList.map((item) => {
      if (checkPagePermission(item) && checkUserPermission(item)) {
        return (
          <Route
            path={item.key.slice(1)}
            key={item.key.slice(1)}
            element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key])}</AuthComponent>}
          />
        );
      }
      return <Route path="*" key={item.key.slice(1)} element={<AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission")}</AuthComponent>} />;
    })}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={"/app"} />} />
  <Route path="*" element={LazyLoad("notFound/NotFound")} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Try to use comments, or explain in a paragraph, exactly which changes you made to the code, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping to a string value using string templating, but then also fail to return a mapped value. You should map to a [`RouteObject`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/context.ts#L15-L47) object instead.

Example:

```js
routeList.map(({ key }) => ({
  path: key,
  element: LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[key]),
})),
```

Complete code:

```
const element = useRoutes([
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: LazyLoad("login/Login"),
  },
  {
    path: "/app",
    element: <AuthComponent>{LazyLoad("sandbox/Sandbox")}</AuthComponent>,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Redirect to="/app/home" />,
      },
      routeList
        // Ensure there is component mapping
        .filter(item => LocalRouterMapping[item.key])
        // Map to RouteObject properties
        .map((item) => ({
          path: item.key,
          element: LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key]),
        })),
      {
        path: "*",
        element: LazyLoad("noPermission/NoPermission"),
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Hello, I have an additional issue using the function LazyLoad, but I am not able to create the component

Comment: @Marcus Looks like it might be a similar issue with string templates. It might just be `LazyLoad(LocalRouterMapping[item.key])`. Can you edit your post to include what this `LocalRouterMapping` object is so we can see what values you are attempting to access?

Comment: Alright I added my LocalRouterMapping and also my data from axios as well

Comment: @Marcus I see, I think that confirms my previous comment. I've updated my answer, please check it out when you can.

Comment: Hmm but it is still always redirect to noPermission page for every path. May I know what's the error? There is no error prompt in the console as well

Comment: @Marcus What is the *it* that is redirecting to the `noPermission` page? When are the routes fetched and when and how are they rendered? Can you again edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] so we can see better what the code is doing?

Comment: Actually, I tried your method and use console.log to get the item.key and element that I wanted, and there is no error, in the routeList.filter.map part is just not creating the path with the component. I attached the whole code for my indexRouter.jsx file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252289/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-marcus).